# object mapping [locations] can't be changed from nested to non-nested

Tags: json, elasticsearch

### Step1:

PUT http://localhost:9200/hindex

```
  {
      "mappings" : {
            "hProvider":{
                "properties": {
                    "iPid"  : { 
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "pType" : {
                        "type" : "string"
                    },
                    "pInfo" : {
                        "properties":{
                            "businessName": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "dob": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "firstName": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "gender": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "index": "not_analyzed"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "locations" : {
                        "type" : "nested",
                        "properties" :  {
                            "addressInfo" : {
                               "properties" : {
                                        "city": {
                                              "type": "string",
                                              "index": "not_analyzed"
                                        },
                                        "county": {
                                              "type": "string",
                                              "index": "not_analyzed"
                                        }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

GET http://localhost:9200/hindex/_mapping

```
{"hindex":{"mappings":{"hProvider":{"properties":{"iPid":{"type":"string"},"locations":{"type":"nested","properties":{"addressInfo":{"properties":{"city":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"county":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"}}}}},"pInfo":{"properties":{"businessName":{"type":"string"},"dob":{"type":"string"},"firstName":{"type":"string"},"gender":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"}}},"pType":{"type":"string"}}}}}}
```

3. Inserting data

POST http://localhost:9200/hindex/prof/1/?_create

```
{
               "iPid"  :  "xyz",
               "pType" : "HealthCareProfessional",
               "pInfo": {
                  "businessName" : "hdata",
                  "firstName" : "Dawoods",           
                  "dob" : "11/18/1975",
                  "gender" : "male"
                },
                "locations" : [
                    {
                        "addressInfo" : {  "city" : "Olney",  "county" : "UnitedStates" } 
                    }, 
                    {
                        "addressInfo" :  {  "city" : "Rivers", "county" : "United States" }
                    }
                ]
}
```

Response :

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"remote_transport_exception","reason":"[node-1][10.194.153.161:9300][indices:data/write/index[p]]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"object mapping [locations] can't be changed from nested to non-nested"},"status":400}
```

Have tried with different data-sets but no luck, what could be the error on the data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your third command is not correct, it's not running on the correct mapping type and it tries to create a new mapping type called `prof` with a non-nested `locations` field, which conflicts with the nested one in the `hProvider` mapping type in the same index.

Change it to this:

```
POST http://localhost:9200/hindex/hProvider/1/?_create
                                     ^
                                     |
                                change this
```